# Nginx url rewrites for changed shop categories

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

We recently moved from Magento 1 to 2, during the move we cleaned up our category urls to be more consistent. For instance we changed:

```
/mens/mens-accessories/mens-wallets
```

to :

```
/mens/accessories/wallets.
```

SEO wise this is really destroying us and was wondering what the NGINX rewrite would be to

a) redirect the old category url to the new one and

b) make old product links work as before so that:

```
/mens/mens-accessories/mens-wallets/product-from-the-category
```

will redirect to:

```
/mens/accessories/wallets/product-from-the-category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the rewrite rule below

```
rewrite ^/mens/mens-(.*)/mens-(.*)$ /mens/$1/$2 permanent;
```

The nginx server should redirect (301) both of your category page and product page

Please note that this is only redirecting one category (`mens`) and products.

If you need redirection on other categories and products, then you would have to write additional rules to accommodate them.